# Add padding to QTreeView Columns

Tags: qt, pyside

I've added a left and right padding to the header of the QTreeView using this QSS code:

```
QHeaderView::section{padding:7px 15px}
```

But the content of the columns is not aligned anymore with the headers.

[image: unaligned QTreeView columns with headers title]

How can I add a padding of 15px ( like in the header ) to the columns' content?

**Edit:** For some reasons I use delegates to draw the content of the `QTreeView`, that's why styling the `QTreeView::item` doesn't work ( like @svlasov suggested ).

`painter.translate(15, 0)` seems to fix this issue, but a weird effect appears when I select a row: the selection is not continuous.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
QTreeView::item {  border: 0px;  padding: 0 15px; }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I've made an edit explaining why this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is rude and crude, but it does what you're asking for in a real simple way for a 3 column QTreeWidget.

```
// Okay, I want to make sure my columns are wide enough for the contents, but I also
// Don't want them squished together. So use resizeColumnToContents, to make them
// as small as they can be to show the contents, then take those widths and add some 
// spacing and then set the columns to the new widths.
m_tree->resizeColumnToContents (0);
m_tree->resizeColumnToContents (1);
int w0 = m_tree->columnWidth (0) + 20;
int w1 = m_tree->columnWidth (1) + 20;
m_tree->setColumnWidth (0, w0);
m_tree->setColumnWidth (1, w1);
```

Comment: Actually, I just re-read your question and it doesn't do what you want, but it does what I wanted when I got here ;-)

Comment: Is it a response or not?